# Insert Retrofit response body in Room

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room, segmentation-fault

I am trying to insert `response.body()` which is a `User` in Room, but I get

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 23714 (AsyncTask #2)
```

It shows in `RecyclerView`, but when I try to cache it my app crash.

Here is the code

```
   private void refreshUser() {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrofit2.Response<User> response=webservice.getUser("1").execute();
                    User fromNetwork=response.body();

                    mUserDao.insertUser(fromNetwork);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) guide for my app.

This is the DAO method

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)    
void insertUser(User user);
```

User entity (response body)

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String uid;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "role")
    private int role;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "topic")
    private String topic;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lab")
    private String lab;

    //constructor, setters and getters
}
```

And the view model

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AppRepository mRepository;

    public UserViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository=new AppRepository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser(String username) {
        return mRepository.getUser(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Dao method, response body and room model?

Comment: I edited my question @Ezzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The `User` delivered by `response.body()` had a wrong value in one field, so Room was lauching an error because it couldn't insert the wrong value in the db.